Symbolic Integral of a symbolic derivative in maxima
Is maxima consistent with the fundamental theorem of calculus? Consider the following:
depends(x,t)$
integrate(diff(x,t),t);

just gives me
                                    /
                                    [ dx
(%o2)                               I -- dt
                                    ] dt
                                    /


which I can't really use. I'd like it to give me x+C where C doesn't depend on time t. And in case I specify the limits (say t0,t1) for the integral, I should get x(t1)-x(t0).
Does anyone know if maxima supports this behavior?

If you write the derivative as 'diff(x(t), t) (i.e. with explicit dependence on t), integrate seems to know something about it: integrate('diff(x(t), t), t) yields x(t). However, the constant C isn't included. I see integrate('diff(x(t), t), t, t_0, t_1) yields x(t_1) - x(t_0) which seems OK. Hope this helps.

According to the documentation:

integrate works only with functional relations represented explicitly
with the f(x) notation. integrate does not respect implicit
dependencies established by the depends function.

For example, with an explicit function:
(%i1) integrate(diff(x(t), t), t);
(%o1)                                x(t)

